# How to save/print a powershell terminal text in the end of a script run through powershell commands?

Tags: powershell

I've a script that needs user inputs, and also let them check all the data being displayed, while script is running, and in the end, save/print all the content, to a file, through powershell commands.

I know that there is a way through, GUI selecting all and copy to a text editor, but this is not feasible in this case.

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Comment: Look into **Start-Transcript** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: Thank you, I've discovered that right after asking here. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Solve this with:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7.3

and,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/stop-transcript?view=powershell-7.3

The code that it needs to be recorded, just need to be between each of these commands.